# How to manually help DbContext understand the changes in this case?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Firstly I already have my own way to solve this but it's some kind of replaying the property settings and not using the change tracking API directly (by accessing the `DbEntityEntry` or even the `ObjectStateManager`.

So I would like to know how the change tracking api can be used directly in this case. Here are the involved classes:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public Class()
    {
        Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual HashSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ClassId))]
    [Required]
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }       
}
```

The scenario here is for separated DbContext, meaning it's hosted on some remote service while the model data is all we have as the input.

```
//suppose we have an existing (loaded before from db) person here
//now on client side, we set its Class to a new instance
//and hope that it should be created after saving
person.Class = new Class { Name = "D" };
person.ClassId = 0;

//now on remote server side, we have the input person
//This is NOT working
using(var tc = new TestContext()){
    tc.Persons.Attach(person);
    tc.Classes.Add(person.Class);
    tc.SaveChanges();
}
```

The above remote code is not working, the instance `Class` can be saved fine but an exception is still thrown (at the line `tc.SaveChanges()`) complaining that there is an inconsistency between principal and dependant. I understand that the newly created `Class` should have its auto-generated `Id` synced to the `ClassId` property of `person` (which is still `0` after saving).

So unless you need 2 calls to `SaveChanges`, the first call is to save `Class` first before updating the `ClassId` for `person` with the second call to `SaveChanges`, something like this:

```
//This is working
using(var tc = new TestContext()){
    tc.Classes.Add(person.Class);
    tc.SaveChanges();

    tc.Persons.Attach(person);
    person.ClassId = person.Class.Id;
    tc.SaveChanges();
}
```

That's of course not a good solution. A very nice solution to this (as I mentioned at the beginning) but it's not using the change tracking api directly. It just tries replaying the changing after attaching the `person`, like this:

```
//This is working
using(var tc = new TestContext()){
    var tempClass = person.Class;
    person.Class = null;
    tc.Persons.Attach(person);
    person.Class = tempClass;
    tc.SaveChanges();
}
```

The above code looks much better and works just fine. But it also looks a bit hacky.

I'm seeking for a good solution using the change tracking API directly and not kind of hacky as in the last snippet of code above.

Comment: AFAIK EF still does not facilitate object-graph merging so working with detached entities will require considerable manual coding to sync back up to persist those changes accurately when entities are re-attached. (frankly, more trouble than it's worth IMO) You can dive the object graph and check against local state to merge, vs. attach each child, grandchild, etc. using Modified/Added/Deleted and SetValues(), though messy, kludgey code.

Comment: @StevePy thanks, I understand the complexity of detached scenario, but in this specific case for my problem, looks like we have a simpler solution. You may want to take a look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the entity state:

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.Entry(person.Class).State = EntityState.Added;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much.

Comment: I'd like to add that setting entity state for `person` to Modified may gen a full update statement which includes even unchanged properties. But I can work around that by simply setting all other (primitive) properties' `IsModified` to `false`. Or simply we just attach the entity and set `IsModified` to true for the only property `ClassId`.